# Spring Boot @Transaction not roll back

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have a service that save 2 entities on database, and an exception can ocurr on saving of the second entity, but in this case rollback is not executed and the first entity is saved in database. Below is my code.

Implementation of my Service. OBS: importProdutoRepository and importSkuService are both autowired.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {DuplicateEntityException.class, Exception.class}, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Override
public ImportProduto cadastraProduto(ImportProduto produto, ImportSku sku) throws DuplicateEntityException, EntityValidationException {

    log.info("Cadastrando produto {}", produto);
    produto = importProdutoRepository.save(produto);

    sku.setProduto(produto);
    importSkuService.saveOnDB(sku);

    return produto;
}
```

Controller.

```
@Autowired
private ImportProdutoService importProdutoService;

/**
 * Cadastra um produto no sistema
 * @param cadastroProdutoDTO
 * @param result
 * @return
 * @throws DuplicateEntityException
 * @throws EntityValidationException
 */
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Response<CadastroProdutoDTO>> cadastra(@Valid @RequestBody CadastroProdutoDTO cadastroProdutoDTO
        , BindingResult result) throws DuplicateEntityException, EntityValidationException {
    log.info("Cadastrando produto {}", cadastroProdutoDTO);
    Response<CadastroProdutoDTO> response = new Response<>();
    ImportProduto produto = cadastroProdutoDTO.getProduto();

    if(result.hasErrors()) {//ERROS DE VALIDAÇÃO RETORNA STATUS 400 E A LISTA DE ERROS.
        log.error("Erro dados de cadastro Produto: {}", result.getAllErrors());
        result.getAllErrors().forEach(error -> response.getErrors().add(error.getDefaultMessage()));
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
    }else {

        response.setData(cadastroProdutoDTO);

        ImportSku sku = new ImportSku(cadastroProdutoDTO.getCodigoDeBarras(), produto);

        produto = importProdutoService.cadastraProduto(produto, sku);
        response.getData().setProduto(produto);

        response.getData().setCodigoDeBarras(sku.getCodigoDeBarras());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using.

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting when saving? Is it a checked or unchecked exception?

Comment: Does you `saveOnDB` and save method annotated with `@Transactional` ? Propagation.Nested

Comment: Db is Mysql, the excpeiton that is thrown is checked, my class DuplicateEntityExcpetion which is in rollbackFor attribute. And my save and my saveOnDB is not transactional annoted, only this service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the engine of both tables was Myisam, then I changed to Innodb and it works fine.